# PHP SimpleXMLElement: How to add dynamic child with ampersand escaping

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xml-generation

I'm using the following code to add dynamic child to an xml node

```
 <?php
   $recordXML = new SimpleXMLElement("<Record></Record>");
   $rowXML = $recordXML->addChild('row');
   foreach ($array as $column => $column_value) {
                $rowXML->addChild($column,$column_value );
            }
```

This code gives `"unterminated entity reference" warning!` when there is an ampresand `&` in any of the `$column_value`, I know `&` can be escaped If we assign the child content as below

```
 $rowXML->column_name = "text & content";
 // gives <row><column_name>text &amp; content </column_name></row>
 // without any warning
```

Now how to use this method to add dynamic child node with ampresand escaping ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically to make it work for you would would have to do something like this:

```
$rowXML->{$column} = $column_value;
```